# Populate an array of mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongoose, populate

I have two collections. One for users and one for clients. Each user has an array of `clientIds` that need to be populated.

I have tried to changing the "reference" in the schema, adding a new reference, but have not figured out the problem.

Request route:

```
const employee = await User.findById(req.params.id)
      .populate("clients")
```

User schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
clients: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "client"
    }
  ]
})  
module.exports = User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
```

Client schema:

```
const clientschema = new mongoose.Schema({
     // Client schema
})

module.exports = Client = mongoose.model("client", clientschema);
```

This returns an empty array for the "clients" field. If I change `.populate()` to `.populate("client")` 
it just returns the client object Ids.

Comment: try `.populate('client',['any field'])`

Comment: @saketh - that just return the array of unpopulated IDs

Comment: What is the result of the `console.log(clients);` after you do `const user = await User.findById(req.params.id); const clients = await Client.find({ _id: { $in: user.clients }}); console.log(clients);`

Comment: Are you sure your ids in the client param of users are valid? It cannot populate clients that don't exist in the client collection.